# Performance moving data from Postgres to SQL Server via SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, postgresql, ssis

I have several large SQL queries that I need to run against a Postgres data source.  I am using SSIS on SQL Server 2008 R2 to move the data.  Because of the way our system is set up, I have to use a tunnel via PuTTY and set up local port redirection.

In the SSIS package, I am using ADO.NET source and destination.  I have PostgreSQL drivers installed, and we were able to get the 32-bit version working.  My package runs, I am getting the data, but the data transformation tasks run painfully slow ... about 2,000 records per second.

Does anyone have experience making a trip to Postgres with static queries and dumping the results into a SQL Server?  Any tips / best practices?

Comment: Sorry, I have not a full answer.
From my experience this speed can be the result of SSH tunnel.
Just check if postgresql or SQL Server are under pressure, or disk on machines. I suggest to take a look to CPU used both by putty and ssh server.
For now just collect these informations and edit the post.
Best practices: depends from the query. If you just need to transfer data i suggest to dump it in a flat file and bulk import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to get the data and store it in a ssis raw file.
Then make your transformation and whatever you like on the raw file data.
After that send it back to DB.

General try not to have many calls to the database.

Comment: You mean have postgres dump out a flat file?

Comment: No. I mean that you will have an "OLE DB Source" Getting the Data from Postgre then a "Raw File Destination" to store local the data.

Comment: I'm getting "source has ntext" fields ... would passing them through a data conversion task slow things down?

Comment: even if it slows a bit thinks it is the best way to do it. but i'm sure the slow down will not be noticeable.